# How to format an array into JSON object using nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi

So, i have an attribute which is array

```json
"errId": [1234, 1235]
```

and I want to format it into

```json
"errId": ["1234", "1235"]
```

How can I do that??

I am trying to use this value to extract data from mongoDb using mongo query, To extract data with specific errId
I was using query **`{"errId": "$.errId"}`** and then split JSON to seperate that mongo document,
but I am not able to extract data and also I am getting an error at **`splitJson`** that my file did not have valid JSON content

Comment: SplitJson is for the content of the FlowFile, it appears you are trying to split an attribute instead? What processors are you using?

Comment: I used split Json at first, I also used extractText but it is extracting the errId wrong way, so I am trying to work on groovy script inside of executescript processor which will handle this kind of scenarios

Comment: Please provide more details, such as screenshots of your GetMongo configuration (or whatever Mongo processor you're using), same output from that processor, your SplitJson configuration, etc.